# Commonly required spare parts for quad bike (e.g. Yahama Grizzly)

Tags: maintenance, yamaha

I run a remote field station in central Africa, and we are purchasing a quad (probably a Yahama Grizzly) to ease access. Given parts and funding are hard to get hold of, I would like to take full advantage of their current availability and get a set of spare parts that will probably be required in the next few years.

Typically weekly usage will be 100km along an old forestry road (dirt track) with some pretty rough patches. It will probably be pulling a trailer.

We will have a maintenance protocol (e.g. washing, drying, spraying with WD40, oil checks and changes) but if there are any other suggestions from people familiar with quads, they would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

There are a few items that would be considered essential regarding maintenance and consumable parts.  Parts on quads that are considered consumable include the standard items such as break pads but also items such as brake levers.  Since the vehicle may tip over, breaking a lever.

## Kit Items

- Tire repair kit.  This would include a good set of rubber plugs and vulcanizing glue.  There are C02 cartridges that can be used to refill a tire.  If you are 20km out from base with a flat, you'll be glad you have this.
- Spare tubes - Even though they are tubeless rims.  Having a few spare tubes is always a good idea for obvious reasons.
- Several Tie Downs - Having tie downs in your kit to hold the quad together if you have had an accident is very nice.  As well, using the tie downs on the carrier racks to secure  is very convenient.
- Duct Tape - Great temporary fix 'tool'
- Carrier Box - A mountable carrier box on the racks to carry spare items and the emergency kit.
- Tool Roll - a minimalist emergency toolkit to put on the vehicle that is never removed.  All bolts are metric.  The popular bolts on the Grizzly are 8mm, 10mm, 12mm, 14mm, 17mm.
- Medium gauge wire roll - Spare wire for when handlebar wires, kill switch wire etc. are cut in an accident. Happens more than you might think.
- Crimp on wire connectors - having crimp on wire connectors for when you need to repair the harness after an accident. Be sure to have the crimp tool as well.
- Spare fuses

## Spare Parts

- One spare rim, minimum.   It seems every team has 'that guy' that if he gets a flat, will drive a vehicle 40km on it, even if he has a repair kit, and destroy the rim.  Have heard the story too many times.  Highly suggest this to be in your spare parts shed.
- Spare tires - A full set at least plus 1.
- Set of handlebars.  Two or three. Handlebars get bent and folded up frequently on quads.  If you can find steel handlebars, they back better, heat them up and get a pipe on he end bend it back.  This does destroy the integrity a bit and if you did it too many times you could snap one off when you're riding and hit a bad bump.  Use caution with this advice.  If you change them out when they get bent and save them in the parts shed, you can recycle them into the system if you're in a pinch perhaps.
- Spare levers - Spare brake levers.  They are aluminum alloy and snap off all the time.  ASV makes a great folding lever.  My son had a penchant for crashing at high speed while he was racing and I managed to have one  of these levers last an entire season while replacing everything else multiple times.
- Spare Headlight lamps
- Spare footbrake pedal
- CV Boots
- I will try and add more ideas for you a bit later.  This could be a good start for you.  Hope this is valuable, best of luck.

Comment: CV boots might be a good idea too.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I'll look into how much of this we can afford!

Answer (score 2):

I spoke to someone who has Grizzlys for similar work here, he suggested the following necessities and spare parts:

- Basic repair kit
- Carburetor
- Spark plugs
- Air filters
- Oil filters
- Brake/throttle cables
- Fuses
- CDI unit
- Starter coil
- Electrical relay

Comment: That's a great list.  If you have the budget for an extra CDI, coil and carb you'd be set.

Comment: The new grizzly uses ECU based ignition.